# SAS select random samples from a dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I understand that to select a random sample, I can use

```
proc surveyselect data = raw_data method = srs n=200000 out=sample_data;
run;
```

However, sometimes my raw_data has the number of records < 200000. If the raw_data is small, I would like to just keep the raw_data; if it's larger than a million records, I would like to randomly select a 200k of records out of it. How should I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: RTM: you will find option SELECTALL

Comment: @data_null_ I think OP wants [N<1000000: nsamp=all] [N>1000000: nsam=200000], so it's a bit more complicated than SELECTALL.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a macro variable for `n`.  You can do this below, or you can use `dictionary.tables` or `proc contents` to get the count without actually counting all of the rows if you don't have reason to disbelieve those values.

```
proc sql;
  select 
    case when count(1) < 1000000 then count(1) else 200000 end
    into :sampcount
    from yourdataset
  ;
quit;

proc surveyselect n=&sampcount. .... ;
run;
```